# SBT cleanup hook in test

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT has a nice hook which allows you to execute arbitrary code after all tests are run:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup( () => println("Cleanup"))
```

That works.
My question is: I want to do some actual cleanup (stopping some services for example) but I can't import any dependencies which I've declared in the same build file. Is there any way to do this? I guess I need to put these on the sbt classpath or something, but I can't seem to find this in the docs.

P.S. I might be doing this in the wrong location, is there a better place to shutdown things after all tests are run?)

Comment: To your P.S. - if you happen to be using ScalaTest, I know there's a `BeforeAndAfterAll` trait that you can mix into your test class(es). From there you just override the `afterAll` method to perform your cleanup.

Comment: That works, I was just wondering how one could make use of that hook

Comment: `afterAll` runs *after each 'spec'* (after each test-class), I'm quite sure... It may suit your needs, but it probably means your "cleanup" routine is running multiple times during each execution of your test-suite (and thus probably slowing things down a tad).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Complementing venechka's answer: I'm running integration tests using Specs2, and in specs there is no way of knowing when all tests have run. So I solved it pretty much the way venechka and you yourself already indicated, by loading a class from the project that does the cleanup when it's initialized:

```
testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Cleanup( (loader: java.lang.ClassLoader) => {
  loader.loadClass("com.mypackage.IntegrationTestCleanup").newInstance
} )
```

Comment: Still a valuable answer ten years later!

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the classes that are added with libraryDependencies in project (you can add libraryDependencies in project/project, but I wouldn't recommend adding in 2 places). Instead you can invoke a cleanup method that is in your project's sources, and that has access to the declared library dependencies.